# How to dynamically bundle javascript files in runtime

Tags: javascript, dynamic, paypal, sdk, bundle

I have a requirement to bundle my javascript modules dynamically during runtime. We are delivering Web SDK to the user. User will pass client id as input in the script src section, something like paypal does `<script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID"></script>`.

Depending on client id, web SDK should be bundles with the features enabled for the client. If we don't filter the features based on client id, the js size will increase and we are exposing some services which they are not supposed to access(ofcourse my backend will prevent if unauthorized request comes).

**Paypal** is dynamically bundling the javascript SDK, based on client id passed? I need implement similar way paypal has implemented.

Extract from Paypal site:

**Load the JavaScript SDK from the PayPal server
Load the JavaScript SDK from https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js only. Reasons include:
The script is dynamically bundled, based on your client ID and the current buyer. It includes only the specific code, images, localization, and other resources needed and does not slow down your page with unnecessary code. This approach is not possible with a statically-distributed script.**

Comment: Dynamic imports will still ship the code to browser (OR) esbundle does support bundle generation in runtime but with static imports only.

Comment: I was able to use Webpack Node JS API, dynamic imports and Webpack DefinePlugin to pass pre-defined variable values dynamically.

I created a simple node js express server and based on API end point route, I initialize Webpack Node API and generate the the bundle and save it to memory and not as a file and return the bundle in memory as attachment to the API endpoint response.

Comment: This may not be the best approach, as for every call the backend has to generate the bundle dynamically. Suggestions are welcome if there are better approaches.

Esbuild bundle is much faster compared to Webpack, but esbuild does not support dynamic imports for bundling.